# Django - queries won't return the targeted column

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-models

What I want to accomplish:

Admin is logging in to see all of the members in his group.
What I get in return is all the members from others group which i do not want.
I only want Admin to see members who are in his group.

I am not getting the filters i want.

Searching for solutions here with no luck and still a newbie so appreciate your help!

admin\models.py

```
class Administrator(AbstractUser):
    ...
    asoc_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Administrator'
```

member\models.py

```
from pl.admin.models import Administrator

class Member(models.Model):
    member_no = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    asoc_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Member'

class Association(models.Model):
    asocnumber = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    asoc_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)


    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Association'


class member_asoc(models.Model):
    asocnumber = models.OneToOneField(Association)
    member_no = models.OneToOneField(Member)
    user = models.OneToOneField(Administrator)


    class Meta:
        db_table = 'member_asoc'
```

Views.py

```
class member_overview(ListView):

    model = Member
    template_name = 'member/member_overview.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        return Member.objects.filter(asoc_name=user)
```

Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a model for Administrator and give it a OneToOneField to Association. Then, you need to create a Member model and give it a ForeignKey relating it to Association.

Then you should be able to do:

```
Member.objects.filter(association=self.request.user.administrator.association)
```

This assumes that your User object is linked to Administrator with a OneToOneField

Comment: It might work but my models does not seem to pass id's through the models. I thougt that would be handled automagically by setting `OneToOne` and `ForeignKey`. Any ideas how i should proceed?